# How do we can send APIs to DialogFlow in any language?

Tags: dialogflow-es

As right now i have some problems regarding APIs query for language. I knew that Cambodian language is not support in DialogFlow and when i wrote in DialgFlow in test within DialogFlow , it works fine but when i'm trying to send through APIs it's not work because resolve query going to be unreadable code. Is there any possible way that we can send it through APIs in another language that is not yet support?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you say Cambodian language, do you mean Khmer? Google Cloud's Translate API (https://cloud.google.com/translate/) supports Khmer, which could help with this.

As far as Dialogflow is concerned, these pages of documentation should help with fulfillment:

https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/language

https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents/multilingual